# Is there any code for refreshing a list after performing CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations

Tags: c#, list, linq

Student Model

```
using System;

namespace Model
{
    public class StudentModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
        public DateTime dob { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Data Acess Layer Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Model;

namespace DataAccessLayer
{
    public class StudentDL
    {
        public List<StudentModel> _students { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creating the by default 2 data list 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Data list</returns>
        public List<StudentModel> GetStudents()
        {
            if (_students == null)
            {
                _students = new List<StudentModel>();

                _students.Add(new StudentModel
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    FirstName = "S FN1",
                    LastName = "S LN1",
                    Gender = "Male",
                    dob = new DateTime(2013, 11, 18),
                    Age = "12",
                    Class = "5th Grade",
                    Address = "Dhaka"
                });

                _students.Add(new StudentModel
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    FirstName = "S FN2",
                    LastName = "S LN2",
                    Gender = "Female",
                    dob = new DateTime(2011, 09, 10),
                    Age = "10",
                    Class = "4th Grade",
                    Address = "Khar"
                });
            }

            return _students;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// GetStudentBySearch method retrieves a list of students based on a search text
        /// filtering the students based on their first name, last name, or age. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="searchText">The text to search in the student records</param>
        /// <returns>Method returns a list of searchResults based on the search criteria of first name, last name, and age.</returns>
        public List<StudentModel> GetStudentBySearch(string searchText)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText))
            {
                return _students;
            }

            string lowerSearchText = searchText.ToLower();

            List<StudentModel> searchResults = _students.Where(student =>
                student.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(lowerSearchText) ||
                student.LastName.ToLower().Contains(lowerSearchText) ||
                student.Age.ToLower().Contains(lowerSearchText)
            ).ToList();

            return searchResults;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds or updates a student record based on the specified ID. If the ID is found, the existing student data is updated. 
        /// If the ID is not found, a new student data is added. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The ID of the student record</param>
        /// <param name="student">The StudentModel object containing the student data.</param>

        public void AddOrUpdateStudent(StudentModel student)
        {
            if (_students == null)
            {
                _students = new List<StudentModel>();
            }
            if (student.Id == 0)
            {
                int Id = _students.Count > 0 ? _students.Max(s => s.Id) + 1 : 1;
                student.Id = Id;
                _students.Add(student);
            }
            else
            {
                StudentModel Updatestudent = _students.Find(s => s.Id == student.Id);
                if (Updatestudent != null)
                {
                    Updatestudent.Id = student.Id;
                    Updatestudent.FirstName = student.FirstName;
                    Updatestudent.LastName = student.LastName;
                    Updatestudent.Gender = student.Gender;
                    Updatestudent.dob = student.dob;
                    Updatestudent.Age = student.Age;
                    Updatestudent.Class = student.Class;
                    Updatestudent.Address = student.Address;
                }
            }
            }

        /// <summary>
        /// Delete the student data 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Id">The ID of the student to be Delete.</param>
        public void DeleteStudent(StudentModel student)
        {
            if (_students != null)
            {
                StudentModel existingStudent = _students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == student.Id);
                if (existingStudent != null)
                {
                    _students.Remove(existingStudent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

StudentBL Page

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Model;
using DataAccessLayer;
namespace BusinessLayer
{
    public class StudentBL
    {
        StudentDL _studentDl = new StudentDL();


        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves all
        /// the students from the data access layer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A list of StudentClass objects representing all the students in the system.</returns>
        public List<StudentModel> GetStudents()
        {
            return _studentDl.GetStudents();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves all students if the search text is empty or null. Otherwise it perform search on student data  and returns the matching results.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="searchText">The text to be searched for in the student data.</param>
        /// <returns>A list of `StudentClass` objects that match the search criteria.</returns>
        public List<StudentModel> GetStudentBySearch(string searchText)
        {
            return _studentDl.GetStudentBySearch(searchText);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Validates the student record by checking the validity of the firstName, lastName, gender, and age fields.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="firstName">The first name of the student.</param>
        /// <param name="lastName">The last name of the student.</param>
        /// <param name="gender">The gender of the student.</param>
        /// <param name="age">The age of the student.</param>
        /// <returns>True if all fields are valid; otherwise, false.</returns>
        public bool ValidateDataFields(string firstName, string lastName, string gender, string age)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName) || firstName.Length < 3 || firstName.Length > 15)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName) || lastName.Length < 2 || lastName.Length > 18)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gender))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(age) || !int.TryParse(age.Trim(), out int parsedAge) || parsedAge < 5 || parsedAge > 99)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds or updates a student record with the specified ID and student data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The ID of the student record.</param>
        /// <param name="student">The StudentModel object containing the student data.</param>
        public void AddOrUpdateStudent(StudentModel student)
        {
            if (student == null)
            {
                _studentDl.AddOrUpdateStudent(student);
            }
            else
            {
                _studentDl.AddOrUpdateStudent(student);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes the student record with the specified ID.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Id">The ID of the student record to be deleted.</param>
        public void DeleteStudent(StudentModel student)
        {
            _studentDl.DeleteStudent(student);
        }
    }
}
```

AddEditPage

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Model;
using BusinessLayer;
using ErrorMeassage;

namespace StudentListApplication_Normal_
{
    public partial class AddEditStudent : Form
    {
        private readonly StudentBL _studentBL;

        private readonly StudentModel _existingStudent;


        /// <summary>
        /// created constructor to call business layer (StudentBL)
        /// </summary>
        public AddEditStudent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _studentBL = new StudentBL();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// It initializes the form and sets control properties based on the "existingStudent" object. It fill text boxes, combo box, 
        /// and date picker with data if "existingStudent" is not null. Used for editing existing student details.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="student"> student is used to fetch the existing Student Data From the Student Model</param>
        public AddEditStudent(StudentModel student)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _studentBL = new StudentBL();
            _existingStudent = student;

            if (_existingStudent != null)
            {
                FirstNameTextBox.Text = _existingStudent.FirstName;
                LastNameTextBox.Text = _existingStudent.LastName;
                GenderComboBox.Text = _existingStudent.Gender;
                DobPicker.Value = _existingStudent.dob;
                AgeTextBox.Text = _existingStudent.Age;
                ClassTextBox.Text = _existingStudent.Class;
                AddresstextBox.Text = _existingStudent.Address;
            }
        }

        //validation
        private bool ValidateDataFields()
        {
            string firstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text.Trim();
            string lastName = LastNameTextBox.Text.Trim();
            string gender = GenderComboBox.Text;
            string ageText = AgeTextBox.Text.Trim();
            var studentBL = new StudentBL();
            bool isValid = studentBL.ValidateDataFields(firstName, lastName, gender, ageText);

            if (isValid)
            {
                // Validation successful
                HideValidationError(FirstNameErrorLabel1);
                HideValidationError(FirstNameErrorLabel2);
                HideValidationError(LastNameLabel1);
                HideValidationError(LastNameLabel2);
                HideValidationError(GenderErrorLabel);
                HideValidationError(AgeErrorLabel1);
                HideValidationError(AgeErrorLabel2);
            }
            else
            {
                // Validation Error
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName))
                {
                    ShowValidationError(FirstNameErrorLabel1, errorMessage.RequiredFieldsErrorMessage);
                    HideValidationError(FirstNameErrorLabel2);


                }
                else if (firstName.Length < 3 || firstName.Length > 15)
                {
                    ShowValidationError(FirstNameErrorLabel2, errorMessage.FirstNameLengthErrorMessage);
                    HideValidationError(FirstNameErrorLabel1);

                }
                else
                {
                    HideValidationError(FirstNameErrorLabel1);
                    HideValidationError(FirstNameErrorLabel2);

                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName))
                {
                    ShowValidationError(LastNameLabel1, errorMessage.RequiredFieldsErrorMessage);
                    HideValidationError(LastNameLabel2);

                }
                else if (lastName.Length < 2 || lastName.Length > 18)
                {
                    ShowValidationError(LastNameLabel2, errorMessage.LastNameLengthErrorMessage);
                    HideValidationError(LastNameLabel1);

                }
                else
                {
                    HideValidationError(LastNameLabel1);
                    HideValidationError(LastNameLabel2);

                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gender))
                {
                    ShowValidationError(GenderErrorLabel, errorMessage.RequiredFieldsErrorMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    HideValidationError(GenderErrorLabel);
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ageText))
                {
                    ShowValidationError(AgeErrorLabel2, errorMessage.RequiredFieldsErrorMessage);
                    HideValidationError(AgeErrorLabel1);

                }
                else if (!int.TryParse(ageText, out int parsedAge) || parsedAge < 5 || parsedAge > 99)
                {
                    ShowValidationError(AgeErrorLabel1, errorMessage.AgeLengthErrorMessage);
                    HideValidationError(AgeErrorLabel2);
                }
                else
                {
                    HideValidationError(AgeErrorLabel1);
                    HideValidationError(AgeErrorLabel2);
                }
            }

            return isValid;
        }

        private  void ShowValidationError(Label validationLabel, string errorMessage)
        {
            validationLabel.Text = errorMessage;
            validationLabel.Visible = true;
        }

        private void HideValidationError(Label validationLabel)
        {
            validationLabel.Visible = false;
        }

        private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ValidateDataFields())
            {
                string firstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text.Trim();
                string lastName = LastNameTextBox.Text.Trim();
                string gender = GenderComboBox.Text.Trim();
                DateTime dobString = DobPicker.Value;
                string age = AgeTextBox.Text.Trim();
                string Class = ClassTextBox.Text.Trim();
                string address = AddresstextBox.Text.Trim();

              

                StudentModel newStudent = new StudentModel()
                {
                    FirstName = firstName,
                    LastName = lastName,
                    Gender = gender,
                    dob = dobString,
                    Age = age,
                    Class = Class,
                    Address = address
                };

                if (_existingStudent != null)
                {
                    _studentBL.AddOrUpdateStudent(_existingStudent);
                }
                else
                {
                    _studentBL.AddOrUpdateStudent(newStudent);
                }
                StudentList studentList = new StudentList();
                studentList.Show();
                studentList.RefreshListView();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }

        private void CancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StudentList studentList = new();
            studentList.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        

        private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(errorMessage.DeleteConfirmationMessage, "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (_existingStudent != null)
                {
                    _studentBL.DeleteStudent(_existingStudent);
                }

                StudentList studentList = new StudentList();
                studentList.RefreshListView();
                studentList.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }


        private void DobPicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dob = DobPicker.Value;
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            int age = currentDate.Year - dob.Year;
            AgeTextBox.Text = age.ToString();
        }

        private void AgeTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ageText = AgeTextBox.Text;

            if (int.TryParse(ageText, out int age))
            {
                DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
                int year = currentDate.Year - age;
                int month = DobPicker.Value.Month;
                int day = DobPicker.Value.Day;
                DateTime updatedDate = new (year, month, day);
                DobPicker.Value = updatedDate;
            }
        }

        private void GenderComboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            e.KeyChar = (char)0;
        }

        private void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != ' ' && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true; // Ignore the key press event
            }
        }

        private void AgeTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != ' ' && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Data is not getting refresh when I  do CRUD operation in C Sharp (list)  it show the same default two data which i added in dataaccesslayer can you help to solve this error I have ulpoded the refresh code and the save button code please help me with the error

Comment: LINQ doesn't write to databases, EF Core does. There's no LINQ or EF Core code in the question. There shouldn't be any need to refresh either the only thing that comes from the database are auto-generated values like IDs. These are handled by EF Core

Comment: Is the real question how to refresh the *grid*? Is `StudentList` the form? If you use data binding, the grid will refresh itself automatically if the source it binds to raises the INotifyPropertyChanged event. Right now you need to call `RefreshListView` on the current form, not display a new one.

Comment: I'm not using databases; instead, I'm doing it with temporary data.

Comment: Try to do the binding using "ItemSource" instead of "DataSource"

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'ItemSource' and no accessible extension method 'ItemSource' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) StudentListApplication(Normal) C:\Users\siddhi gada\source\repos\StudentListApplication(Normal)\StudentListApplication(Normal)\StudentList.cs 58 Active

Comment: Do not post code in comments, it is unreadable. Update your question if necessary. Also, add relevant tags. Is this a winforms program? Webforms? Etc. "list" is meaningless here.

Comment: Are `studentBL` and `_studentBL` different things? Presumably it should be the same thing. And creating a new StudentList (presumably a badly named form) should be not neccessary. You presumably want just `this.RefreshListView()`.

Answer (score 0):

When using a [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=net-7.0) and [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) in tangent with implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-7.0) as shown below there is no need to touch the DataGridView and added or edited data is shown without a refresh.

In the example below, everything is done in the form while for your code you need to adjust e.g. take out how I load data for instance.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WinFormsApp1;
public partial class NoRefreshForm : Form
{
    private BindingList<StudentModel> _students;
    private BindingSource _source = new BindingSource();
    public NoRefreshForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shown += OnShown;
    }

    private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add several students
        List<StudentModel> students = new List<StudentModel>
        {
            new StudentModel() { FirstName = "Anne", LastName = "Jones" },
            new StudentModel() { FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Adams" }
        };

        _students = new BindingList<StudentModel>(students);
        _source.DataSource = students;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _source;
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add a new student, will show up in the DataGridView
        _source.Add(new StudentModel() { FirstName = "Mike", LastName = "Smith" });
    }

    private void EditCurrentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get current student from DataGridView current row
        StudentModel student = _students[_source.Position];
        // update properties
        student.FirstName = student.FirstName + "!";
        student.LastName = student.LastName + "@";
    }
}

// class belongs in its only file
// INotifyPropertyChanged - Notifies clients that a property value has changed.
public class StudentModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get => _firstName;
        set
        {
            if (value == _firstName) return;
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get => _lastName;
        set
        {
            if (value == _lastName) return;
            _lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```